# Dual boot Ubuntu for Android on my Galaxy Note 2?

Tags: ubuntu-for-android

Has Ubuntu released "Ubuntu for android" yet? I read on their web page all about the product but no download link or install guide? I have a Galaxy note 2 and would really like to dual boot it and start trying it out!! http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android

Answer (score 1):

No. Ubuntu alongside android was not released. Most probably ubuntu edge going to be the first device (if the funding succeed).